# Taylor series - calculating sin(x) until 6 digits precision

Tags: java, trigonometry, taylor-series

I must calculate sin(x) with a Taylor's series, until the output has 6 decimal places. The argument is an angle. I didn't implement checking the decimal places, I'm just printing next values (to check if it's working), but after 10-20 iteration it shows infinities/NaN's.

What's wrong in my thinking?

```
public static void sin(double x){
    double sin = 0;
    int n=1;
    while(1<2){

        sin += (Math.pow(-1,n) / factorial(2*n+1)) * Math.pow(x, 2*n+1);
        n++;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }

        // CHECKING THE PRECISION HERE LATER
        System.out.println(sin);
    }
}
```

the Equation:

[image]

Comment: why do you want to do that? Shall the code be a numerical aproximation? Then your probaly shall check your decimals, as you stated.

Comment: This is the problem. Task:
Implement a sin(x) method which calculates a sin(x) with Taylor's series with 6 digits precision. << That's all I have.

Serie is infinite, I think that this '6 digits' are the loop end condition.

Comment: And does the code work?, post the result, input value, and output fo each iteration. Is the value wrong after the first 9 iterations? Maybe 10 iteration are to much, and don't write formulas in one line, you cannot debug them, use a variable for each term: like double divisor = factorial(2 * n +1); Further some mathematic concept do not work well in computer programs. So you probaly have got some information how this numericaly shall be solved.

Comment: And where is your problem? I dont see NaNs in the value you posted, and later deleted., just do the convergence check, after 10 iterations you are ready in your example, of course the answer of FredK is professional. but first try to get your solution to work. As you can see in FredK answer, your naive solution is numerically not well suited. There is an own course "numerical mathematics" that deals with such things.

Comment: Tipp. diff = newSin - oldSin; while( Math.abs(diff) > 1E-7) { do your code }

Comment: Outputs are the same as in FredK answer (I copied his code) but it still gives out: 3.14 with param Math.PI.
Something is really wrong.

Comment: Use first your code, and do the convergence check, as I posted.Then later think wether or not to use a professional numerical apporach., similar to that of FredK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compute each term using factorials and powers! You will rapidly overflow.
Just realize that each next term is -term * x * x / ((n+1)*(n+2)) where n increases by 2 for each term:

```
double tolerance = 0.0000007; // or whatever limit you want
double sin = 0.;
int n = 1;
double term = x;
while ( Math.abs(term) > tolerance ) {
  sin += term;
  term *= -( (x/(n+1)) * (x/(n+2)) );
  n+= 2;
}
```

Comment: sin(Math.PI) gives 3.14 O.o :D Bug somewhere

Comment: should be Math.abs(term) > tolerance

Comment: @Qbix if you copy his solution for your homework, consider changing the tolerancde level, You probably cannot answer why he used 7 as last digit. And this would be my first question, to you.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answer provided by @Xoce (and @FredK), remember that you are computing the McLaurin series (special case of Taylor about `x = 0`). While this will converge fairly quickly for values that are within about `pi/2` of zero, you may not get convergence of the digits before the factorial explodes for values of `x` further than that.

My recommendation is to use the actual Taylor series about the closest value of `sin(x)` for which the exact value is known (i.e., the nearest multiple of `pi/2`, not just about zero. And definitely do the convergence check!

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

NAN error is normally a really big number, something that can happend if you divide 2 numbers but the divisor is very small, or zero.

## Solution

This happens because your factorial number is getting an overflow, and later at some point you are dividing by zero again
if your factorial is taken as argument an int, then change it by , for example, a `BIgInterger` object.

Comment: yeah, that's correct, after 10-20 iteration it get's huge, but 0-10 output is kinda random, that's why I'm asking what's wrong :(

Comment: Using BIgInteger is not a solution,. probably the author shall implement "checking the decimals" as he stated.